# How to display name of data piece that comes from a foreign key in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to get the view to show a name of a category instead of just the ID.

Here's my code:

Models:

```
    public class Category
    {
        [Key]
        public string Cat_ID { get; set; }
        public string Cat_Name { get; set; }
    }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public class SubCategory
    {
        [Key]
        public string SCat_ID { get; set; }
        public string SCat_Name { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("SCat_Cat")]
        public string SCat_Cat { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    }
```

SubCategory controller (the view part):

```
        public SubCategoriesController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        // GET: SubCategories
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.SubCategory.ToListAsync());
        }
```

Code that is supposed to view the Category Name

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SCat_Name)
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.Cat_Name)

            </td>
```

So I'm trying to make this part `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.Cat_Name)`show the Category name. Right now I'm getting nothing at all.
Oh and here's database record.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had to change this:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.SubCategory.ToListAsync());
        }
```

To this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.SubCategory.Include(u => u.Category).ToListAsync());
        }
```